Ideal , subring and subspace of a linear algebra over a field
Let V be a finite dimensional linear algebra with identity over the field F (R or C). Definition of a linear algebra over the field F is as given in the book "Linear Algebra" by Hoffman and Kunze. By this definition V is also a ring with respect to the same vector addition and vector multiplication with the same multiplicative identity. My questions are the following:

Is it true that any ideal of V (V as a ring) is also a vector subspace of V (V as a vector space) and vice versa?

Is it true that any subring of V (V as a ring) is also a vector subspace of V (V as a vector space) and vice versa?

What can be said if V is assumed to be commutative?


I know that any ideal of a ring (commutative or noncommutative) is also a subring of the ring but in general the converse is not true. Thanks in advance for any help.


Yes. 2. No. 3. It doesn't change the answer. Try playing around with some examples. Also, this use of the term "linear algebra" is very nonstandard and likely to be confusing; the standard term for what I think you're describing is "associative algebra."


The definition of a linear algebra in Hoffman-Kunze is what is more commonly known as an (associative) algebra over a field. It seems that you are also assuming the existence of identity, which would make it a unital algebra. Googling this should give you all the information you want. Regardless, the answers are

True, but not vice versa. As a counter-example to the reverse, take the $\Bbb{R}$-algebra of polynomials $\Bbb{R}[x]$, and consider the vector space of polynomials of degree $\leq n$. This is clearly not a subring, thus not an ideal.

False in both cases. Above is a counter-example to the reverse, and a subring in $\Bbb{R}[x]$ that is not a vector subspace is $\Bbb{Z}[x]$.

Assuming commutativity does not help in any direction, since all my examples above are commutative.



Thank you very much @SomeCallMeTim. Can you please give some hint for why an ideal is a vector subspace. I am finding it difficult as scalar multiplication is not defined in a ring.

If your algebra has identity, which it seems that you assume, then the underlying field embeds into your algebra $A$ as $\Bbb{F}\to A$ by $x\mapsto x\cdot 1$. Then clearly being closed under multiplication from $A$ implies closed under scalar multiplication. If your algebra is not unital, you may need to be more careful.

Now it is absolutely clear to me. Thank you very much once again for the response.
